# AMP Pages UCBrowser GA PageViews not tracking

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html, uc-browser

We are running a eCommerce aggregator portal on WEB and WAP both. Recently we have migrated whole WAP pages to AMP. After migration, the GA sessions for UC Browser has been decreased by almost 95%. We have figured out some of the devices which are not sending the pageview event however the website is working fine. Can anyone help to debug UC Browser?

Thanks,

Vidosh

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with my site.....sessions have dropped a lot for UC browser after creating amp pages